# 2D & 3D Question on planar curves

Tags: geometry

I thought of a circle $x^2+y^2=4$ on a XY plane ....then assumed to cut the circle circulary & hang it in XYZ space ....Then it is really confusing to know if the above said circle maintain its planar property?

now can u please tell me if so cut ring has torsion zero or what?

Comment: what does *"cut the circle circulary"* mean?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "hang it in XYZ space". If you mean "view the circle as $\{(x, y, z) : x^{2} + y^{2} = 4, z = 0\}$", does the question answer itself?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Maybe it'll help it you include a sketch.